# Should I write "dried" or "dried out" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> I blinked at this woman, so many times my eyes almost dried (out)
>   completely.

I searched on [Google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=%22my%20eyes%20almost%20dried.%22&oq=%22my%20eyes%20almost%20dried.%22) and I found both instances:

> My eyes almost dried out completely and were more bloodshot than
>   they'd ever been, mild visual hallucinations but mainly auditory.
>
> ... or hsv I got up in the mid night with my eyes almost dried. Out of
>   lazyness to see the time I took my saliva n spread in my eyeballs to
>   lubricate.

Are both options correct? Or only one?

Comment: That second sentence was written by a person who is not a native speaker. It is not idiomatic English.

Comment: I doubt many people use "almost dried" in this context. "dry eyes" has more of a medical context. Referencing tears would be better. Perhaps "my tears almost ran out"?

Comment: There is [*dry-eyed*](https://www.google.com/search?q=dry-eyed) but the meaning is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrasal verb "dry out" suggests completeness, it is often used (for example) of laundry. It can suggest a return to "proper" dryness, from a state of dampness or moistness. But as your example shows, both dry and dry out are used of eyes.

You could use either dry or dry out; it is up to you. I would use "dry out", since it goes with "completely"

I find your sentence a little odd, since blinking wets they eyes. When your eyes are dry, you blink to make them wet again.